# Diameter comparison for manifolds with $\text{Ric}\ge 0$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with $\text{Sec}\ge 0$. From Topogonov Theorem follows that for every $p \in M$ the quantity
$$
\frac{\text{Diam}(B_r(p))}{r}
$$
is non-increasing in $(0,\infty)$.  Does this hold also if we only assume $\text{Ric}\ge 0$? I suspect that this is no longer true, however I am not able to build a counterexaple.

Clarification: $\text{Diam}(B_r(p)):=\sup_{x,y\in B_r(p)}d(x,y).$

Comment: It is a theorem due to  [Abresch-Gromoll](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1990-03-02/S0894-0347-1990-1030656-6/S0894-0347-1990-1030656-6.pdf) that diameter growth is linear. **Any complete Riemannian manifold
with $Ric \geq 0$ has diameter growth of order $O(r)$ with respect to any point**.

Comment: The notion of diameter  growth in that paper is not the one I am interested in, here by $\text{Diam}(B_r)$ I mean the supremum of $d(x,y)$ among all $x,y \in B_r$, which clearly implies $\text{Diam}(B_r)\le 2r.$

Comment: I would try to modify the Perelman's example http://library.msri.org/books/Book30/files/perex.pdf